# Swipe delete button not showing when swiping from embedded button

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a custom `UIButton` with an image placed on the right side of the cell. If the user taps on the button then swipes left at some point in the swipe `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` is called and the image on the button is dimmed.

This is what you would expect when the delete button is revealed, however, the cell never slides to reveal the delete button. If the user taps in the area where the delete button would be the cell is deleted.